# the import javax.media cannot be resolved

Tags: media-player

I am trying to make a media player for a project in java for school and it says that the imports for javax.media cannot be resolved and any help would be appreciated. Below is the code iI have used.  Like I said if anybody can help me to figure it out it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.media.CannotRealizeException;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MediaPlayer<Player> extends JPanel
{
private Player mediaPlayer;
private Component Video;
private Component controls;

public MediaPlayer (URL mediaURL) throws IOException
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout() );

    Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true);

    try
    {
        Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaURL);

        Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
        Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

        if (video != null)
            add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        if (controls != null)
            add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    catch (NoPlayerException noPlayerException)
    {
        System.err.println("No media player found");
    }
    catch (CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException)
    {
        System.err.println("Could not realize media player");
    }
    catch (IOException iOException)
    {
        System.err.println("Error reading from the source");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Media Framework is an optional package. I believe you have to download it separately.

> The Java Media Framework API (JMF) enables audio, video and other
>   time-based media to be added to applications and applets built on Java
>   technology. This **optional package**, which can capture, playback,
>   stream, and transcode multiple media formats, extends the Java 2
>   Platform, Standard Edition (J2SE) for multimedia developers by
>   providing a powerful toolkit to develop scalable, cross-platform
>   technology. [(source)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)

After downloading it, you need to add it to your classpath.

Comment: i downloaded it but i still cant get it to resolve my issues in the media player that i am tryin to program

Comment: You need to add it to your classpath.

Comment: oh ok, sorry im still new at this, how would i open and add it to the classpath?

Comment: You can't learn Java by asking questions on StackOverflow. You need to read Oracle's Java tutorials, like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html.

Comment: How would i open and add it to the classpath?